# Visible and gone the fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have to develop an one android application.

Here i have to check the value.If the value is Null means have to hide the fragment.otherwise visible the fragment.How can i do ???

please give me solution for these ..

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
              .beginTransaction();

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, fragment); 
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
       _Video = articlevideo.substring(1);
       fragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {


            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.cueVideo(_Video);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                    YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            }

        });





      String vid = "Null";
        if(_Video.equalsIgnoreCase(vid))
        {

      //Gone the fragment      
        }
        else
        {

          //Visible the fragment      

        }
```

How can i hide the fragment on these activity...

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#414042"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="#414042"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
     <fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <WebView
                android:id="@+id/fullcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#414042"
               android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_fragment"
                 />



  </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can i hide the fragment ??? please give me solution ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  `yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

`yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` //This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes

and `yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` //This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

Comment: String vid = "Null";
        if(_Video.equalsIgnoreCase(vid))
        {
fragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else
        {

 fragment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } means  am getting following error on these line:The method setVisibility(int) is undefined for the type YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Comment: i have created separate layout for these fragment and also done GONE and VISIBLE functionlaity for that layout. Now i got it.thanks.